# How to match (group2.*|^.*)group1 when no instance of groups 1,2,3, or 4 are in between?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm using Python 3.4.

Suppose we have four groups composed of regular expressions

```
g1 = 'g11|g22|...|g1m'
g2 = 'g21|g22|...|g2n'
g3 = 'g32|g32|...|g3p'
g4 = 'g41|g42|...|g4q'
```

For example, `g1` might be `'chickens|horses|bonnet(?>!blue )'`. The groups are disjoint:  no element in any of the four groups belongs to more than one group.  The groups can have any number of elements greater than 1.

### I want to match on a string **if and only if** it contains **any** instance of group_1 such that either :

1. no instances of any of groups 1-4 precede **said** instance of group_1 or
2. the instance of any of groups 1-4 that immediately precedes **said** instance of group_1 is not group_2.

#### Some strings on which I want to match:

1. `'g11'`
2. `'g31 g11'`
3. `'g41g11'`
4. `'g11 g21 g11'`  (The second instance of g11 violates rule 2.  The first instance of g11 does not and moreover rule 1 is satisfied.)
5. `'anything or nothing g11 anything or nothing'`
6. `'anything or nothing g31 anything or nothing g11'`

#### Some strings on which I don't want to match:

1. `'g31 g21 g11'`
2. `'g21 g11 g31'`
3. `'anything or nothing g21 anything or nothing g11 anything or nothing'`

#### What've tried so far:

- I tried:  `(g31|g32)(?=.*?(g11|g12))(?!.*?(g21|g22))`, which works for
  `'g31 g11'` and `'g31 g21 g11'` but fails if there is a g21 or g22 after g11, as in `'g31 g11 g21'`.
- I've also tried `'(g31|g32).*?(g21|g22){0}.*?(g11|g22)'` which works for `'g31 g11'` and `'g31 g21 g11'` but not `'g31 g31 g21 g11'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!(?:(?!g1|g2).)*(?:g21|g22)(?:(?!g31|g32|g41|g42).)*(?:g11|g12)).*?(?:g11|g12).*$
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/16

Comment: Yes.  I'll edit:  "I want to match on any strings containing an instance of group_1 if either..." to "I want to match on strings if and only if they contain an instance of group_1 and either...:

Comment: I'm looking for any instance of g1 such that either i) no instance of any group precedes that instance of g1 or ii) the instance of any of the four groups that immediately precedes said instance of g1 is not g2.  The second instance of g1.  The first instance of g1 does not violate rule 2 and also rule 1 is satisfied.  I'll edit again.  If it's still not clear, please let me know.

Comment: Did you suggest an edit?  Looks like it was purged by my last edit.  If you suggest it again, I'll accept it.

Comment: @epistemicFUN i meant check my latest answer if it works for you

Comment: Can it be made to match `'g21 g11 g11'`?  The second of the two g11 instances is satisfactory.